# How to update only the part of page

Tags: asp.net

I have several combo boxes and labels.  when a user select any item from the combo box, the corresponding value will be retrieved from database and will be shown on the label. I have done these part successfully.

But my query is, when I select any item from the combo box, the whole page posts back to the server (AutoPostBack set to ***True***.)

is it possible to post back only a part of page not the whole page (i.e. only combo box controls may be posted back to server instead of whole page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to achieve that. In ASP.NET there is the [UpdatePanel control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) which might help you.